# Change Solidity struct into json in web3.js result

Tags: json, solidity, web3js

I am new to solidity and js. I define a struct in solidity struct and return the struct directly like this.

```
struct data{
    uint256 serialNum;
    address ownerAddress; er
    string ownerName;
    string id; 
    string name; 
    uint256 point;
    uint256 category;
    string description; 
    bool isOpen;
    bool isUsed;
}
function getDataInf(uint256 _serialNum) public view returns(data memory){
    data memory res = Dataset[_serialNum];
    return res;
}
```

I use web3.js get the struct and I get the result

```
[
  '1',
  '0x9f3ca236fE5903ad64FFDbBca0E1ad70ED66646b',
  '超级账户',
  '84',
  '难那层布',
  '75',
  '6',
  'Ut ea sint non',
  false,
  true,
  serialNum: '1',
  ownerAddress: '0x9f3ca236fE5903ad64FFDbBca0E1ad70ED66646b',
  ownerName: '超级账户',
  id: '84',
  name: '难那层布',
  point: '75',
  category: '6',
  description: 'Ut ea sint non',
  isOpen: false,
  isUsed: true
]
```

The result is exiciting to me. I use typeof function and I find it is an object. I would like to ask how can I change the object into an json object. If I use `Json.stringify`, I just get the value list. It is amazing for me.